# How to make image view scrollable in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, shrink, image-enlarge

How to make a image view scroll vertically. Demo images are uploaded below.

How to shrink image view?

Image 1.   [image]

Image 2.    [image]

Image 3.    [image]

when user scroll up `imageview` get shrink from image 1 view to image .3 view

when user scroll down `imageview` get enlarge from image 3 to image 1

How to acheive this. Is this possible to replicate in android

Comment: The key term for this is `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. If you search on google you can find some really good examples like this: https://github.com/hearsilent/AmazingAvatar

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such a behavior with CoordinatorLayout
https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Unfortunately i won't do a solution for you. You can find example code [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml).

Comment: I tried using coordinate layout but I am not able to achieve that. If possible can you make solution for me. I am new to android. That's why I am asking. Thankyou